# The problem when updating a react component when it is set with append

Tags: javascript, reactjs

let me describe the problem a little:
I have a chat to which I can only add a react component in the following way

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

const responseRef = useRef(message);

const FormattedMessage = (messageId) => {
        return <p id={messageId} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: responseRef.current }} />;
    };

const messagesContainer: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('messages');

            const messageClients: HTMLCollectionOf<Element> = messagesContainer.getElementsByClassName('rcw-message-client');

            const lastMessageClient: Element = messageClients[messageClients.length - 1];

            if (lastMessageClient) {
                const answerElement = document.createElement('div');
                answerElement.className = 'rcw-message';

                const formattedMessage = <FormattedMessage message={message} />;
                ReactDOM.render(formattedMessage, answerElement);

                lastMessageClient.parentNode.insertBefore(answerElement, lastMessageClient.nextSibling);
            }
```

Everything is ok so far, the component receives append.
But I would like when I receive SSE messages from an event, to update the messages in the component and to be formatted even as html and code.
I proceed like this

```
responseRef.current += event.data;
setMessage(responseRef.current);

useEffect(() => {
    responseRef.current = message;
}, [message]);
```

Likewise here, the messages are updated in states, but not in that

in the component.
How could I proceed?